# Why do I need to show that the sequence defined by $a_{n+1} = f(a_n + 1) - f(a_n)$, $a_1 = 1$ is well-defined, where $f'(x) > x$ on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I have a function $f$ which is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ such that:

$$
\forall x > 0: f'(x) > x.
$$

Also we have a sequence:

$$
a_{n+1} = f(1+a_n) - f(a_n),\quad a_1 = 1.
$$

Now, the answer says that they want to prove that the sequence is well defined, therefore they will prove that $\forall n \in N: a_n > 0$

Why is there this condition that "we will prove that the sequence is well defined"?

What is the term well-defined for sequences? I know it for functions, but what is the meaning for sequences?

Comment: OHHH its because of the interval in which the function, which the sequence is defined by, is defined -> and we have $f(a_n)$ so if the sequence is defined it must hold $a_n > 0$.....

Comment: Do you mean $a_{n+1} = ...$?

Answer (score 3):

Since the sequence $(a_n)$ is defined in terms of the function $f \colon (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ by:
$$
a_{n+1} = f(a_n + 1) - f(a_n), \quad a_1 = 1,
$$
the sequence $(a_n)$ is *well-defined* only when you are actually able to compute the values $f(a_n + 1)$ and $f(a_n)$ for every $n$ inductively from this definition.

What can go wrong? Suppose that for some $n_0$ it turns out that $f(a_{n_0} + 1) \leq f(a_{n_0})$, then you will have $a_{n_0 + 1} \leq 0$. But then in the next step you will not be able to compute $f(a_{n_0 + 1})$ since $a_{n_0 + 1}$ is outside the domain of $f$.

So, the well-definedness check here is that $a_n \in (0,\infty)$ for all $n$. The hypothesis that $f'(x) > x$ will be used in proving well-definedness.